# MST with least number of edges

Tags: data-structures, minimum-spanning-tree

How to write the logic to select minimum spanning tree - path with least number of edges if there are multiple short path available ??

Here is my java code -- which selects minimum spanning tree path , but not the one with least number of edges ..

```
  import java.io.BufferedReader;
  import java.io.InputStreamReader;


 public class Kruskal {

   static int path[];
      static int n, m, mincost, i, j;

      public static void main (String args[]) throws Exception {

 InputStreamReader isr;
 isr = new InputStreamReader(System.in);
 BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(isr);

 // Creating graph of 'n' vertices & 'm' edges
 System.out.print("Enter the number of vertices in the graph: ");
 n = Integer.parseInt(in.readLine());

 System.out.print("Enter the number of edges in the graph: ");
 m = Integer.parseInt(in.readLine());

 path = new int[n+1];

 Edge e[] = new Edge[m];
 Edge t = new Edge();

 for (i=0; i<m; i++) {
   e[i] = new Edge();
   System.out.println("Enter 2 vertices and weight of edge: ");
   System.out.print("First vertex: ");
   e[i].u = Integer.parseInt(in.readLine());
   System.out.print("Second vertex: ");
   e[i].v = Integer.parseInt(in.readLine());
   System.out.print("Weight: ");
   e[i].wt = Integer.parseInt(in.readLine());
 }

 // Sorting the edges in ascending order of weights
 for (i=0; i<=m-1; i++) {
   for (j=0; j<m-i-1; j++) {
     if (e[j].wt > e[j+1].wt) {
       t = e[j];
       e[j] = e[j+1];
       e[j+1] = t;
     }
   }
 }

 // Initializing the path array
 for (i=1; i<=n; i++) {
   path[i] = 0;
 }

 // Counts the number of edges selected in the tree
 i = 0;

 // Counts the number of edges selected or discarded
 j = 0;

 mincost = 0;
 System.out.println();
 while ((i!=n-1) && (j!=m)) {
   System.out.print("Edge ("
   + e[j].u + ", " + e[j].v + ") "
   + "with weight " + e[j].wt + " ");
   if (checkCycle(e[j])) {
     mincost = mincost + e[j].wt;
     i++;
     System.out.println("is selected");
   } else {
     System.out.println("is discarded");
   }
   j++;
 }
 if (i!=n-1) {
   System.out.println("Minimum spanning tree cannot be formed ");
    }

   }

       public static boolean checkCycle(Edge e) {
         int u = e.u, v = e.v;

           while (path[u] > 0)
           u = path[u];

      while (path[v] > 0)
           v = path[v];

      if (u != v) {
      path[u] = v;
        return true;
       }
       return false;
    }

        static class Edge {
         int u, v, wt;
        }
       }
```

Output :

[output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DK8Lk.jpg)

Comment: I don't understand the question; each spanning tree of a graph has the same number of edges, as for instance discussed [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/454639/how-many-edges-does-an-undirected-tree-with-n-nodes-have).

Comment: There are cases where 2 or more mst will have equal weight but unequal number of edges ..  A-->B (1 weight)  , B -->c (2 weight),        A-->D (1 Weight) , D-->E (1 Weight) , E -->C (1 weight ) .                                                                  2 MST paths:                                                                                         A-->B-->C  (total weight= 3)                                                                   A-->D-->E-->C (Total weight =3 )

Answer (score 1):

The short answer from Codor's link:

> How many edges does an undirected tree with n nodes have?
>
> This is a very standard fact; any basic text will tell you that an undirected tree with n nodes must have exactly n−1 edges.

In your example (from the comment), you listed two paths but they are **not** a minimum spanning tree. A minimum spanning tree (MST) or minimum weight spanning tree is a subset of the edges of a connected, edge-weighted undirected graph that connects **all** the vertices together.

Comment: Exactly; apparently the question demands for something else than a spanning tree.